# When passing list of dictionary to serializer getting error " "Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"." in django rest framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

```
    serializer = BookingCancellationSerializer(
        data=payload,
        context={"request": request},
        many=True
    )
```

data:
{
"schedule_booking": [6892, 6893],
"booking_type": "lesson",
"remarks": "xyz"
}

What is the right way to pass a list of lists to the serializer programmatically?

or

In which formate I should pass the data to the serializer?

Tha data which I am trying to pass is something like this... [['schedule_booking': 6892, 'booking_type': 'lesson', 'remarks': 'xyz', 'created_by': 253], ['schedule_booking': 6893, 'booking_type': 'lesson', 'remarks': 'xyz', 'created_by': 253]]

Comment: What is your desired output? Can you show us exactly how it should look?

Comment: There is no way for us to guess at what `BookingCancellationSerializer` might be doing with this stuff; I'm assuming it's some internal tool. Without a [MCVE] (you didn't even provide a traceback for us to guess *where* the problem is), this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [`many=True`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializing-multiple-objects) option is for passing a list (or queryset) of objects, not a single dictionary, hence the error message.

If you're serializing a single dictionary, omit `many=True`.

Comment: I need to pass  list of lists how can I do that?

Comment: See my edit. If you're only serializing a single dict, you don't need `many=True`. After all, you're serializing *one* thing, not *many* things.

Comment: something like this... [['schedule_booking': 6892, 'booking_type': 'lesson', 'remarks': 'xyz', 'created_by': 253], ['schedule_booking': 6893, 'booking_type': 'lesson', 'remarks': 'xyz', 'created_by': 253]]

Comment: @mayankgupta Wait. Your question showed `data` as a single dictionary. Are you doing something different now? Also that's not even valid; each sublist has keys like a dictionary. Lists and dictionaries aren't the same thing.

Comment: I need to pass the multiple list at once?

Comment: wanna see my code?

Comment: You're asking multiple different questions. Specify what you're trying to do and please stop changing your mind.

Comment: ok, Here's the data I need to pass into my serializer {'schedule_booking': [6892, 6893], 'booking_type': 'lesson', 'remarks': 'xyz', 'created_by': 253} how can would i do that?

Comment: payload = {'schedule_booking': [6892, 6893], 'booking_type': 'lesson', 'remarks': 'xyz', 'created_by': 253, 'update_by': 253}

Comment: serializer = BookingCancellationSerializer(
            data=payload,
            context={"request": request},
            many=True
        )

Comment: That's what you said originally in your question. I already answered that. Just remove `many=True`.